# Por alguma razão, quando eu digito a resposta, não acontece nada, quem conseguir me ajudar a consertar esse código, agradeço

Tags: java, if

Por alguma razão, quando eu digito a resposta, não acontece nada, quem conseguir me ajudar a concertar esse códio, agradeço

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){         
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String resposta;
   System.out.println("Quanto é 2 + 2?");
   resposta = in.nextLine();
   if(resposta == "4")
       System.out.println("Resposta correta!");
   
            
}
```

}

Comment: string devem ser comparadas com o equals, `if("4".equals(resposta))` ja deve funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Quando estamos trabalhando com `String`, a melhor forma de realizar comparações é utilizando o  método `.equals(elemento)` e não o `"=="`. Este último, só deve ser utilizado quando estamos uzando tipos primitivos. Por exemplo; int, double, boolean. Abraços!

```
if(resposta.equals("4")) {
   System.out.println("Resposta correta!");         
}
```